# How to include/find other files in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I want to call my javascript function from my nodejs script, but I'm getting an `Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined` error.

My server has this:

```
  require('/public/js/script.js')();
  foo();
```

and my javascript file has this:

```
    module.exports = function() {
        this.foo = function() {
            //do stuff
        };
    }
```

I also am getting an `Error: Cannot find module '/js/script.js'` in my terminal when trying to start the website. Am I importing the javscript file with the wrong path or something?

Comment: `/js/script.js` is an absolute path.  Maybe you want a relative path: `./js/script.js`?

Comment: the file is not the problem. it should have been opening error rather than reference error. there must be a problem with definition.

Comment: @Devon I tried that before and it still gave me an error/didn't work.

Comment: @ReiDien What kind of definition problem?

Comment: can you show your folder structure?

Comment: Yes: the server code is in a file called index.js. next to index.js is a folder called "public." inside the folder "public" is a folder called "js." inside the folder "js," is the script file script.js

Comment: Then use `require('./public/js/script.js')`

Answer (score 0):

if you're requiring module that reside in the node_module then you can just put

`require('module-name');` node resolve this by looking in the node_modules folder

if you want to require module on your working directory you need to specify the '.' or '..'
`require('./folder/subfolder/script')` '.' will let you navigate the current and sub folder directory

`require('./../outsideFolder/subfolder/script')` '..' will let you navigate the outside folder directory of your current folder.